# How can I use Python to aggregate data from multiple directors in various companies into one figure per company using Blau's Index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains categorized data about the educational backgrounds of the directors of several companies. Currently, each company (recorded by its ticker) has multiple entries, one per director, and the df looks something like this:

```
Ticker  Education
ABC     1
ABC     1
ABC     5
ABC     7
ABC     5
DEF     3
DEF     4
DEF     4
DEF     4
DEF     6
```

I want to use the Blau's Index formula (same as the Gini-Simpson Index) to create a new dataframe with only one entry per company as follows:

```
Ticker  Education Diversity
ABC     0.64
DEF     0.56
```

The formula used is (1 - ∑p<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>) where p<sub>i</sub> is the proportion of directors in each of the i education categories; e.g. for company ABC, p<sub>1</sub> = 2/5.

Can anyone help me implement this in Python (3.7)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try implenting your own `def` then use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). Finally, [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to get back to `DataFrame` format:

```
def blaus_index(arr):
    return 1 - sum((arr.value_counts() / len(arr)) ** 2)

df.groupby('Ticker')['Education'].apply(blaus_index).reset_index(name='Education Diversity')

  Ticker  Education Diversity
0    ABC                 0.64
1    DEF                 0.56
```